# How to set a new key Redis callback

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I can set a key in Redis with:

```
client.set("tmpkey", 100, "EX", 100);
```

But this function does not set a key when called inside the callback of another Redis function (KEYS or SCAN):

```
var client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_PORT, process.env.REDIS_HOST);          

client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

client.keys("TAG:*", function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
    client.set("TMP", 100, "EX", 100);
});

client.quit(function (err, res) {
  console.log('Exiting from quit command.');
});
```

How can I set a value in Redis after scanning the existing keys?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Where do you define client?

Comment: there are no error messages, simply does not set a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the client.quit() was called before the callback of client.keys() function was completely executed.

Moving client.quit() into the callback of client.keys() solved the problem for me.

```
client.keys("TAG:*", function(err, res) {
  console.log(res);
  client.set("TMP", 100, "EX", 100);

  client.quit(function (err, res) {
    console.log('Exiting from quit command.');
  });
});
```

But the better solution would be using Promises.

Answer (score 0):

Guess something with your redis library. Should work the same.

> But this function does not do the same

What does it do?

Comment: I am using node-redis.

Comment: it simply does not set that key. unfortunately, it does not return any error messages

Comment: I guess KEYS command works too long so you should wait long time while next line code to be executed. How many keys do you have in your database?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redis-node with version 4.1.0 or newer, you can try:

```js
// params: KEY, VALUE, OPTIONS
client.set("TMP", 100, { EX: 100 });
```